# java sql prepared statement doesn't escape correctly for postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

I was using PreparedStatement in Java to create sql command for postgresql, however all placeholder are escape with single quote, which is different from postgresql requirement where double quote is used.

below this the log and error msg

```
2021-06-22 18:33:08,157 INFO  [ai.tus.map.fea.per.uti.MapperHelper] (executor-thread-199) Insert prepared statement: wrapped[ insert into "known_fruits" (?) VALUES (?) ]
2021-06-22 18:33:08,158 INFO  [ai.tus.map.fea.per.uti.MapperHelper] (executor-thread-199) Insert statement: wrapped[ insert into "known_fruits" ('name') VALUES ('ddf') ]
2021-06-22 18:33:08,159 ERROR [ai.tus.map.fea.FruitResource] (executor-thread-199) Failed to handle request: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 29
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130)
        at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:88)
```

the corresponding code is:

```
        LOGGER.info("Insert prepared statement: " + stmt.toString());
        for (int i = 1; i <= fieldNum; ++i) {
            stmt.setString(i, existFields.get(i - 1).name);
            stmt.setObject(i + fieldNum, existFiledVals.get(i - 1));
        }
        LOGGER.info("Insert statement: " + stmt.toString());
```

**edit:**

the sql string I wanted to build:

```
insert into "known_fruits" ("name") VALUES ("ddf")
```

the sql string I put into PreparedStatement with placeholder is:

```
insert into "known_fruits" (?) VALUES (?)
```

the final sql string I got is:

```
insert into "known_fruits" ('name') VALUES ('ddf')
```

as @Andreas pointed out, I should not use `?` for table name or column name, they're only for value injection. So my question would be is there any approach to safely make sql handle escaping regaridng table name or column name? Since these value are runtime-determined, I don't know whether there would be some table name same as sql keyword that need to be escaped.

Comment: You can't use `?` parameter markers to inject identifiers such as table and column names. You can only inject *values*. You have to use string concatenation to insert the column names, then `?` to handle the values.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the complete SQL String you are building.

Comment: @Andreas is there anyway to let sql safely inject table name or column name? since these are still runtime value I don't know whether I need to escape them

Comment: `values ("ddf")` would be wrong to begin with as `"ddf"` refers to a column name. It's not a SQL string constant

Comment: Why wouldn't you know the names of your tables or columns?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was writing a simple SQL template generator, which might accept several entity tables on runtime

Comment: Is the table and column names coming from a trusted source? If yes, e.g. a hard-coded list somewhere else in the code, then you don't need escaping. If no, e.g. they are header names from a CSV file, then you absolutely need to validate or escape the names. --- If you intend the names to be unquoted *(recommended)*, then you should simply validate that the names only consist of valid characters, which basically means matching regex `\w+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a parameter for the column name, like in

```
insert into "known_fruits" (?) VALUES (?)
```

You will have to construct a query string that contains the column name as a literal.

Comment: OP never wrote `$1`, the **JDBC driver** replaced `?` with `$1`.

Comment: @Andreas Ah, I see, yes. I have fixed the answer.